# Websocket with Laravel - Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, websocket

I have using Websocket with Laravel. And I cloned the project on server too. And also I checked the domain name with [SSLserver Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).It shows the domain name in **A** grade and the certificate from Cloudflare.

For WSS I used this [tuitorial](https://medium.com/@errohitdhiman/real-time-one-to-one-and-group-chat-with-php-laravel-ratchet-websocket-library-javascript-and-c64ba20621ed)
I ran the websocket as following `wss://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080` and use the domain name as https://mydomainname.biz` to use the websocket. But while viewing the console on Google Chrome it shows **WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

But I already mapped the **cert** file and the **key** file for the secure websocket connection. Laravel Websocket Code as follows:

Artisan command to start : `php artisan websocketsecure:init`

```
        $webSock = new SecureServer(
            new Server('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop),
            $loop,
            array(
                'local_cert'        => '/home/virtfs/users/etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.crt/server.crt', // path to your cert
                'local_pk'          => '/home/virtfs/users/etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.key/server.key', // path to your server private key
                'allow_self_signed' => FALSE, // Allow self signed certs (should be false in production)
                'verify_peer' => FALSE
            )
        );
```

Comment: `wss://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080` seems to imply you're accessing the websocket via its IP. (the 4 parts of 3 digits seem to imply that).

Comment: @apokryfos, yeah, I am using via IP. But it works in some browsers

Comment: I'm not sure if it should work in some browsers. If the certificate is issued against the hostname it should not be able to verify the IP address. Since shared hosting is so common having your certificate verify the default page on a shared host is probably not a good idea.

Comment: So, how can I reach this.

Comment: Try accessing the websocket using the hostname instead of the IP address.

Comment: Since I have the cPanel and able to use https://mydomainname.biz and its subdomain. It is harder to map. Is there any possibility?